Use `structlog` in a library while respecting `stdlib` log configuration
I'm looking to use structlog in a Python library, but would also like to transparently support the logging configuration set up by a containing application. In particular:

if a log level is set (e.g. via logging.basicConfig), respect that
support the standard pytest logging fixture (including the configured log level)

As this is a library, making global changes to the structlog or logging configuration isn't appropriate.
So far, the best I have been able to come up with is to expose a public API along the lines of:
import logging
import structlog.stdlib

def use_stdlib_logging(log_level: int|None = logging.INFO):
    """Configure SDK logging to use stdlib logging with the given log level.

    Note: this alters the default global structlog configuration.
    """
    structlog.stdlib.recreate_defaults(log_level=log_level)

While this would work, it means every embedding application needs to know to call that API - by default, the library would completely ignore the standard library's logging config.

My conclusion after asking structlog's author the same question is that it really is an application logging framework.
For a library (which isn't directly responsible for the overall logging configuration), something like the structured logging recipe in the standard library is a better approach.
For my use case, I also incorporated a small logging module wrapper that adds the event message and data to the extra_data field in addition to logging the serialised json.
